# Reduce horizontal gap between figure and caption when placed beside using floatbox

Tags: floats, captions

I am using `floatbox` to place my caption on the right side of my figure but there is a gap of around 1/8th line width between the figure and the start of the caption as shown. Can I reduce this and move my caption right beside my figure as it looks weird!

Code used to generate the below image:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},capbesidewidth=.35\linewidth}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{This is a caption describing this figure as needed. The caption can contain any text but needs to desribe the image with enough detail for a reader to completely understand the image.}
{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{image1}}
\end{figure}
```

This is how it looks in my document:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify this horizontal spacing in `\thisfloatsetup` with the `capbesidesep` key. As said in `floatrow`'s [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow), this key can be assigned the values

- `columnsep`, which adds a `\columnsep` horizontal skip,
- `quad`, which adds an horizontal skip of `1em` (the length of a `\quad` command),
- `qquad`, which adds an horizontal skip of `2em` (the length of  a `\qquad` command),
- `hfil`, which behaves like `\hfil`,
- `hfill`, which behaves like `\hfill`,
- `none`, which doesn't add any horizontal skip.

So you can choose between those keys to place correctly your figure, or you could define another key using `\DeclareFloatSeparators`. For example,

```
\DeclareFloatSeparators{mysep}{\hskip3em}
```

defines a `mysep` key which adds an horizontal skip of `3em`. Using this command, you could even add negative values of horizontal skips.

Here's an example of three figures with different horizontal skips, one of them being defined with `\DeclareFloatSeparators` to insert a negative skip.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{mysep}{\hskip-1em}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},
                                     capbesidewidth=.42\linewidth,
                                     capbesidesep=quad}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{\texttt{capbesidesep=quad}. This is a caption describing this figure as needed. The caption can contain any text but needs to desribe the image with enough detail for a reader to completely understand the image.}}
{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},
                                     capbesidewidth=.42\linewidth,
                                     capbesidesep=none}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{\texttt{capbesidesep=none}. This is a caption describing this figure as needed. The caption can contain any text but needs to desribe the image with enough detail for a reader to completely understand the image.}}
{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},
                                     capbesidewidth=.42\linewidth,
                                     capbesidesep=mysep}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{\texttt{capbesidesep=mysep}. This is a caption describing this figure as needed. The caption can contain any text but needs to desribe the image with enough detail for a reader to completely understand the image.}}
{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much I knew there would be a way to control it, I just couldn't find the right command. Works perfectly!